# Parsing JSON Array in Codenameone fails

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use PropertyBusinessObject.getPropertyIndex.loadJsonList(storage) to load a list of propertybusinessobjects. It keeps failing for this json which I have verified as valid json.

```
[{
  "_id": "5e8ef0485053da7500020c79",
  "name": "CriminalAct",
  "description": "A criminal act",
  "label": "Criminal Act",
  "_created": "2020-04-09T09:52:08.689Z",
  "comment_services": [
    "5c49c41840e295040000582a",
    "5c49c2b140e2950400005811",
    "5b632dfabba4456c000002b1"
  ],
  "service_attributes": [
    "5ba1192eda1139170000482c",
    "5e8f02c45053da7500020d04",
    "5e8f03355053da7500020d08",
    "5e8f03d45053da7500020d0e",
    "5e8f06585053da7500020d23",
    "5e8f08c35053da7500020d35",
    "5e8f0c035053da7500020d58",
    "5c347ec511f06f26000027a4",
    "5c3471f711f06f26000025fe",
    "5c347d2811f06f2600002768"
  ],
  "category": [
    "5ca7939d0eaf051400001c5f",
    "5d8e2f84bc58cd2800000854",
    "5e8ee9655053da7500020c41"
  ],
  "parent": [],
  "providers": ["5a57a54c9d89946a00002216"],
  "logo": ["5e8ef2a15053da7500020c8e"]
}]
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
[EDT] 0:0:2,193 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 9 buffer: 
[EDT] 0:0:2,197 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
[EDT] 0:0:2,198 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:495)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.endArray(JSONParser.java:625)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:387)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:484)
    at com.codename1.properties.PropertyIndex.loadJSONList(PropertyIndex.java:667)
```

I am quiet puzzled as to what could be wrong.

Comment: Can you file an issue on this? It seems to be a bug in the `JSONParser` class. https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/